# Use of JButton array Java

Tags: java

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to create 4 buttons using the arrays and passing the method to the Set Panel class. When I run it I only get one button. Any help would be great. Essentially what I want is a Panel with four buttons, through the use of Methods.

```
public class SetButtons extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    JButton [] buttonArray = new JButton[4];
    JButton exitBtn, newGameBtn, checkBtn, clearBtn;
    Font myFont = new Font("ink free", Font.BOLD,22);

    public SetButtons(){


       
        this.exitBtn = new JButton("Exit");
        this.newGameBtn = new JButton("New Game");
        this.checkBtn = new JButton("Check Answer");
        this.clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");

        this.buttonArray[0] = exitBtn;
        this.buttonArray[1] = newGameBtn;
        this.buttonArray[2] = checkBtn;
        this.buttonArray[3] = clearBtn;

       

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            this.buttonArray[i].addActionListener(this);
            this.buttonArray[i].setFont(myFont);
            this.buttonArray[i].setFocusable(false);
            this.buttonArray[i].setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == this){
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}





import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SetPanel extends JPanel {
   
    Font myFont = new Font("ink free", Font.BOLD,22);
    SetLabels labels;
    SetButtons exitButton;

    
    SetPanel(){
        SetButtons btn = new SetButtons();
        this.add(btn);
        this.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    }

}
```

Comment: SetButton extends JButton. so you are adding one single JButton. One that doesn't make sense, but still.

Comment: Btw, having a button array like this doesn't make sense as well. The buttons seem to have special and distinct meanings so accessing them as `exitBtn`, `newGameBtn` etc. makes more sense than `buttonArray[0]` etc. If you want to provide common settings to those buttons try a method that constructs one and returns it, e.g. `exitButton = createButton("Exit", theExistActionListener);`. This leads to the next issue: don't use a single action listener for all of them but use separate listeners as the actions will likely be quite distinct (right now all buttons would have "exit actions).

Comment: One last thing: `this.buttonArray[3].setLayout(new FlowLayout())` doesn't make sense either as buttons normally don't have any child components to layout.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to GUI development in Java. I am trying to make sense of it now. Do you have any reading recommendations?